# how to remove water stain in sanded wood furniture

Tags: wood, furniture, stain, refinishing

I have stripped the paint and sanded down a wood cedar chest.  The top still has a deep circular stain that I think is from water.  I keep sanding the area but the ring still persists.  Do I bleach the stain or keep sanding?  Do I use steel wool or finer sanding paper greater than 100 grit?  I would like to use clear polyurethane on the chest and not have to paint it.

Comment: The stain almost certainly runs too deep to be removed. The best thing is just to accept it as part of the piece's history. If it really bugs you, hide it under a fruit bowl or something. (I knew one kid who added a symmetrical pattern of coffee stains over the whole top.)

Comment: I would recommend looking at the [woodworking.se] sister site - there is a _ton_ of info there on finishing and refinishing. If you don't find _exactly_ what you're looking for, there is a wealth of knowledge to help with this specific issue.